# Question concerning sigma notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation, divergent-series

Consider you have been given that

> $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}i = -\dfrac{1}{12} $$

How do you solve this sigma notation? I've not seen this kinda sigma notation before.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the sum over $i$ of $i$, where $i\in\mathbb{N}$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$. So then that summation becomes $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i = 1+2+3+\cdots$$ The result of that summation is explained by the technique of [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), because obviously that sum doesn't converge in the standard sense.

Most of the times to differentiate the Ramanujan summation from the standard summation we put the symbol $\Re$ somewhere over the summation sign, something like this $$\sum_{i}^{\Re}i$$